# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable in creating tortoise orm model

Tags: fastapi, tortoise-orm

I am trying to test my endpoint and i keep getting this error.

This is how i registered my models :

```py
register_tortoise(
    app,
    db_url='postgresql://user:pass@localhost:5432',
    modules={'models': ['db.models']},
    generate_schemas=True,
    add_exception_handlers=True,
)
```

this is my test_client function. I'm trying to create new profile for users.

```py
def test_create_profile():
    
    new_profile_data = {
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "email_address": "john.doe@example.com",
        "city": "New York",
        "phone_number": "123456789",
        "job_prefernece_title": "Software Developer",
        "job_prefernece_type": "Full-time"
    }

    
    token = "my_token"

    
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {token}"
    }

    
    response = client.post("/create_profile", json=new_profile_data, headers=headers)

    
    assert response.status_code == 200

    
    assert response.json() == {
        "user": "<username>",
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "email_address": "john.doe@example.com",
        "city": "New York",
        "phone_number": "123456789",
        "job_prefernece_title": "Software Developer",
        "job_prefernece_type": "Full-time"
    }
```

this is the error i get

```py
def _router_func(self, model: Type["Model"], action: str):
    for r in self._routers:
    TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Every time I try, I get the same error.
I checked the connection to the database and I am sure that the connection is established.

Comment: It seems like self._routers could be None. Can you print it out above the for loop to verify this and show more of the code so we can see where it is initialized?

Comment: I am trying to print it out in the site packages but i get print(r) NameError: name 'r' is not defined **bold** `def _router_func(self, model: Type["Model"], action: str):
        for r in self._routers:
            print(r)
            try:
                method = getattr(r, action)
            except AttributeError:
                
                pass
            else:
                chosen_db = method(model)
                if chosen_db:
                    return chosen_db`

Answer (score 0):

I got similar error like above:

```
for r in self._routers:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

In my case, it happens because database connection not initialized yet (I forgot to call initialization code).
Are you sure the connection is established? maybe can check with simple get query to make sure.